# Specify model order in multiplot() function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the multiplot() function in R with the coefplot() function to create a plot with coefficients from several models.

```
multiplot(mod1, mod2, mod3, mod4, mod5, mod6, mod7, mod8, mod9, 
      intercept = F, zeroType = 1, 
      zeroColor = 'black', 
      title = 'The Effect of Masculinity on Sexism Items',
      ylab = 'Masculinity Index',
      plot.shapes = T,
      xlab = 'Sexism',
      sort = 'natural', 
      legend.reverse = F,
      names = c('Control', 'Offend', 'Prob', 'Protect', 'Rescue',
                'R/W', 'Equal', 'Hire', 'Harass'),
      newNames = c(masc_ind = 'Masculinity'))+
scale_color_manual(values = c('green', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 
                            'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red'))+
scale_shape_manual(values = c(15,16,17,18,19,0,1,2,5))
```

Which produces the above plot: [image]

I noticed that the order of the models does not follow the order they are entered into the code (ie: mod1, mod2, mod3). Instead, the models appear to be listed in reverse alphabetical order. I know there are some ways to override this in ggplot() for factor level variables in a single model, but I haven't been able to find much in the way of reordering models in ggplot(). Is there a way to override this so I can list the models in a preferred order?

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of your `mod*` objects passed to `multiplot`? (Just a thought.)

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything. I think it has to do with the fact that the names = argument overrides this and will list the models in alphabetical order. Even if I rename the objects themselves instead of using mod* and drop the names argument, it still orders them alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty with ggplot wrappers like `multiplot` is that often what you gain in ease-of-use, you lost in flexibility. However, the data frame that `multiplot` produces for its plot data is a very nice little summary table. This can be used to plot directly in ggplot however you choose.

Obviously, we don't have your data, but I have created a data set with all the same names and structure as your own (see below), so the following code should work for you:

```r
library(coefplot)

var_names <- c('Control', 'Offend', 'Prob', 'Protect', 'Rescue',
               'R/W', 'Equal', 'Hire', 'Harass')

plot_data <- multiplot(mod1, mod2, mod3, mod4, mod5, mod6, mod7, mod8, mod9, 
          intercept = F, zeroType = 1, 
          zeroColor = 'black', 
          title = 'The Effect of Masculinity on Sexism Items',
          ylab = 'Masculinity Index',
          plot.shapes = T,
          xlab = 'Sexism',
          sort = 'natural', 
          legend.reverse = F,
          names = var_names,
          newNames = c(masc_ind = 'Masculinity'))$data

p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(Value, factor(Model, rev(var_names)), color = Model)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = LowOuter, xmax = HighOuter), height = 0) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = LowInner, xmax = HighInner), height = 0, size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = var_names), size = 4) +
  labs(x = "Sexism", y = "Masculinity Index") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

p + scale_color_manual(values = setNames(c('green', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 
                                           'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red'),
                                         var_names), name = "Variable") +
    scale_shape_manual(values = setNames(c(15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 0, 1, 2, 5),
                                         var_names), name = "Variable")
```

[image]

And of course you can style this however you choose:

```r
p + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_manual(values = setNames(rep(c("red3", "orange2", 
                                      "steelblue4"), each = 3), var_names),
                     name = NULL) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = setNames(c(15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 0, 1, 2, 5),
                                       var_names), name = NULL) +
  labs(x = "Sexism", y = "Masculinity Index") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)

var_names <- c('Control', 'Offend', 'Prob', 'Protect', 'Rescue',
               'RW', 'Equal', 'Hire', 'Harass', 'masc_ind')

df <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(500, 1, 0.5), 50)), var_names)

list2env(setNames(lapply(head(var_names, -1), function(x) {
  df2 <- data.frame(masculinity = df[[x]], masc_ind = df$masc_ind)
  do.call("glm",
          list(formula = masc_ind ~ masculinity, 
               data = quote(df2), 
               family = quote(binomial)))
}), paste0("mod", 1:9)), globalenv())
```